# Does Koa need Forever?

Tags: node.js, forever, koa

Koa has implemented not having a web server shut down when one page has an error. My question.... is this error handling behaviour robust enough that one no longer needs to use Forever when hosting a node site?

Comment: Just want to note that `forever` does a lot of other things like letting you specify log file outputs, watch directories, and control multiple applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should still use `forever` (or `nodemon`, a bit easier to use in some cases) to keep your server running. There are other things that can cause it to crash in a production environment, not just bad requests.

In development, I've seen insane uptime on some koa apps without using `forever`/`nodemon`, but I would not do this in production. It's asking for a 3 am phone call :)

If you're using Linux/Unix, you should also consider using `tmux` to keep it running in a separate terminal session, or it can timeout with your terminal session. (Type `tmux new -s koa` to get started). Here's an article on using `tmux` with `upstart`: https://bowerstudios.com/node/953